# Simulating a Flyback converter using Matlab / Simpowersystems, cannot get it to work, any tips?

Tags: simulation, matlab, power-electronics, flyback

I have created a flyback converter model using Simpowersystems in Simulink/Matlab. But it always gives me the wrong answer! I have simulated the same system using PLECS and Simscape/simulink and got the correct answer. But with my Simpowersystems model, it always gives me the wrong answer here is a link to the model

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6h6e219x65o6ldk/aKKEgl3Y_D

Any idea what is going on? I tried changing the solver but without luck

Here is a picture of the model

[image]

Comment: What Andy says - plus, some simulators do not like pure inductances. I have NOT looked at your model, but if the inductors are ideal try adding a very small series R.

Comment: I have run the sim with the correct fet orientation so the pure inductance isn't an issue in this case. Yes the diode does flip -ve and +ve

Answer (score 3):

There may be a couple of things wrong in your picture: -

[image]

Firstly, the diode maybe the wrong way round if you are expecting a positive output and secondly the phasing of your transformer may need inverting - try reversing the connections on the secondary - a flyback must have the correct phase relationship between primary and secondary for it to work.

I would also say that your FET appears to be upside down - look at the parasitic diode - it will always be conducting from the battery through the primary.

Comment: You're right about the diode, but this direction was intentional, I am expecting a negative output. The transformer model in this simulink toolkit is not very flexible, I can only have positive outputs. So I think this the only way to connect it when both dots are up.

You are right about the MOSFET! I cannot blieve I missed that :D thank you so much!

Comment: However the problem still stands 

Here is the correct simulation results using PLECS
http://prntscr.com/2bfx0b

ANd here it is using matlab
http://prntscr.com/2bfyqk

Comment: And those were using the same exact parameters :(

Comment: @user34188 don't be silly about the transformer - just swap the wiring - do a cross over. Flybacks need dots at opposite ends but swapping the output wires does the same.

Comment: I'll correct myself (for being silly) - if the output is meant to be negative then the dots need to both be at the top. Sorry